# How to change the starting day of the jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js which is sunday to monday?

Tags: timepicker

I have used the timepicker add-on "jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js". How can I customize this add-on in such a way that the starting day of the week will start on Monday instead of Sunday?

Answer (score 2):

In exactly the same way as you would customise a standard datePicker; set firstDay = 1. For example:

```
$( ".selector" ).datetimepicker({ firstDay: 1 });
```

See http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-firstDay.